# Better way to update TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are in the process of some data integration and I get update scripts in the form of

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.field1 = '12345' WHERE Table1.field2 = '345667';
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.field1 = '12365' WHERE Table1.field2 = '567885';
```

Table1.field2 is not indexed.

The scripts run without problems, but it takes forever. 8000 rows affected in a bit over 7 minutes, which I feel is a bit long. (It's running on a dev server which is not the best, but a look at the server doesn't indicate that it is overly busy).

So my question is, is there a better way (i.e. faster) to run this type of update statements. (SQL 2008 R2)

Many Thanks!

Comment: This is probably due to the lack of an index. I get from your question that you cannot add an index on `Table1.field2`?

Comment: I was thinking about this, but while I might be able to do this in dev, it might be problem later in production.

Comment: It might also be a problem in production if it takes too long. If you have a suitable INDEX create and DROP statement it shouldn't be a problem. However you should test that when you run in the initial INDEX CREATE time it actually is shorter overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be RBAR-ing (row-by-agonizing-row) the server with multiple `UPDATE` statements.  Essentially, you're having it do a table scan for *each* query, which is obviously non-ideal.  While an index would help the most, executing multiple single-value statements will still cost you.

SQL Server allows you to use `JOIN`s for update statements, so you may see some improvement doing something like this:

```
WITH Incoming AS (SELECT field1, field2
                  FROM (VALUES('12345', '345667'),
                              ('12365', '567885')) i(field1, field2))
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.field1 = Incoming.field1
FROM Table1
JOIN Incoming
  ON Incoming.field2 = Table1.field2;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/edb76/2/1)</kbd>

If it turns out that the number of rows in `Incoming` is large, you should probably realize it as an actual table that you bulk-load into first.  You should be able to put an index on the load table (refreshed after the import, to make sure statistics are correct).

But really, an index on `field2` should probably be the first thing, especially if there are multiple queries that use that column.

Comment: This looks interesting. I will give this a try and report.

Comment: indeed a better approach.. if there is no index

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you can try different things (like storing all values on another table, then updating one using the other), but in the end, the engine is going to search using a single field, testing equality with a value.

That would require an index. If you can at least test in dev, maybe you can show the performance improvement to someone who can authorize the creation of the new index in the production environment.

That's my answer, I hope someone comes up with a better one!